# Generalize $H^1_{dR}(X)=\mathrm{Hom} (\pi_1(X),\mathbb R)$ to fundamental Groupoid

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fundamental-group, groupoids

Let $X$ be a path-connected smooth manifold, it is known that: $$H^1(X):=H^1_{dR}(X)=\mathrm{Hom} (\pi_1(X),\mathbb R).$$ Explicitly, a closed one-form $\alpha$ gives a function on $\pi_1(X)$ by $[\gamma]\mapsto \int_\gamma \alpha$; and this only depends on the de Rham class $[\alpha]$ and the homotopy class of $[\gamma]$ due to Stokes' formula. So it is well-defined.

Now, let's consider the fundamental groupoid $\Pi_1(X)$ (objects are points of $X$ and morphisms are the homotopy classes of paths). We also take a closed one-form $\alpha$, then it seems that we can also get a map in a similar manner:
$$
\mathrm{Mor}_{\Pi_1(X)}(p,q) \to \mathbb R, \qquad [\gamma]\mapsto \int_\gamma \alpha
$$
where $p,q\in X$ and $\gamma$ is a path between $p$ and $q$. Although another path $\gamma'$ in the same homotopy class $[\gamma]$ will again yields the same value, the difference is that this is not invariant if we replace $\alpha$ by some $\alpha +d \eta$. Namely, we have to stay at $Z^1(X)$ and cannot go to $H^1(X)$. But in view of $H^1(X)=\mathrm{Hom} (\pi_1(X),\mathbb R)$, the collection of $\mathbb R$-valued homomorphisms on the morphism spaces of the fundamental groupoid $\Pi_1(X)$ should be still related to $Z^1(X)$ in some sense, I guess.

In short, as $\Pi_1(X)$ is often viewed as a generalization of $\pi_1(X)$, it should be interesting to ask in analogy: what should be a reasonable `generalization' of $H^1_{dR}(X)=\mathrm{Hom} (\pi_1(X),\mathbb R)$?

Comment: Take $\mathbb{R}$ as a one-object groupoid and consider functiors to it from $\Pi_1(X)$? What you wrote is only true for connected manifolds anyway :-) Functors from $\Pi_1(X)$ to a one-object groupoid arising from an abelian group factor through the abelianisation of the fundamental groupoid (see eg [section 1.4.3 of this pdf](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/hha/1999/0001/0001/HHA-1999-0001-0001-a001.pdf), and I'm pretty sure a homomorphism $\pi_1(X)^{ab} \to \mathbb{R}$ extends uniquely to $\Pi_1(X)^{ab}$.

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced about my last claim, though...

Comment: In your formulation, each $\alpha\in Z^1_{dR}(X)$ gives a functor $\int \alpha\colon \Pi_1(X)\to(\ast//\mathbb{R})$, and each $\eta\colon X\to \mathbb{R}$ determines a natural  isomorphism between such functors.  So an element of $H^1_{dR}(X)$ determines an isomorphism class of  functors $\Pi_1(X)\to (\ast//\mathbb{R})$.  I think every such isomorphism class arises from a unique cohomology class: you probably need to use the equivalence between de Rham and singular cohomology to prove that.

Comment: Here's a possible fancy-pants formulation: recall that a *Picard groupoid* is a strictly symmetric monoidal groupoid in which each object and morphism is strictly invertible.  The category of Picard groupoids is equivalent to the category of 2-step chain complexes $C=(C_1\to C_0)$: the associated Picard groupoid $\mathcal{G}(C)$ has object set $C_0$ and morphism set $C_0\times C_1$.  You can form the free Picard groupoid $\mathcal{F}(G)$ on a groupoid $G$.  The claim is  is then that $\mathcal{F}(\Pi_1(X))=\mathcal{G}(C_1(X)/B_1(X)\to C_0(X))$, where these are singular chains.

Comment: Then it should be formal that $\mathrm{Fun}(\Pi_1(X), \mathcal{G}(A\to 0)) \approx \mathrm{Fun}^\otimes(\mathcal{F}(\Pi_1(X)), \mathcal{G}(A\to 0))$, which should be the Picard groupoid associated to the function chain complex of maps from $(C_1(X)/B_1(X)\to C_0(X))$ to $(A\to 0)$, and so in particular that isomorphism classes of functors correpond exactly to elements of $H^1(X,A)$.  I think ....

Comment: @CharlesRezk Thank you. Your comments look very enlightening, especially the identity you wrote: $\mathcal F(\Pi_1(X))=\mathcal G(C_1(X)/B_1(X)\to C_0(X))$. Would you mind indicating some references or even writing an answer for this if possible? I think it could be most helpful and solve my problem.

Comment: @Hang I don't know a reference, though I'm positive someone somewhere has worked all this out.  I'll see if I can write an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one possibility.

If $Y\subset X$ is a closed submanifold, one can consider the relative de Rham cohomology $H^n(X,Y)$, which is the quotient of the closed $n$-forms whose restriction to $Y$ is $0$, modulo derivatives of $(n-1)$-forms whose restriction to $Y$ is $0$. 
 Given a class $[\omega]$ in $H^1(X,\{p,q\})$, we get a map $f_{[\omega]}:\mathrm{Mor}_{\Pi_1(X)}(p,q) \to \mathbb R$, $[\gamma]\mapsto\int_\gamma\omega$. The map $f_{[\omega]}$ is not a group homomorphism ($\mathrm{Mor}_{\Pi_1(X)}(p,q)$ is not a group), but it is a heap homomorphism, meaning $f_{[\omega]}( [\gamma_1\gamma_2^{-1}\gamma_3])=f_{[\omega]}([\gamma_1])-f_{[\omega]}([\gamma_2])+f_{[\omega]}([\gamma_3])$. For each $p$, $q\in X$, there is an identification
$$
H^1(X,\{p,q\}) = \operatorname{Hom}(\mathrm{Mor}_{\Pi_1(X)}(p,q),\mathbb{R}),
$$
where Hom means the set of heap homomorphisms.

Answer (score 3):

I think the context to generalize to is this:

Let $G$ be a Lie group, and $\pi$ the fundamental group of a manifold (assumed finitely generated).  Let $\rho\in Hom(\pi, G)$ be smooth, and $[\rho]\in Hom(\pi,G)/G$ where the quotient is some context-appropriate approximation to the conjugation orbit space (examples: the GIT quotient if $G$ is complex reductive, the orbit space if $G$ is compact, or the polystable quotient if $G$ is real reductive).  Then the tangent space to $[\rho]$ is $T_{[0]}(H^1(\pi;\mathfrak{g}_{Ad})/Stab(\rho))$.

In your setting you don't see the quotient since your group is abelian, and you don't see the tangent space since your hom-space is a vector space.

So now consider the fundamental groupoid $\Pi$ (again assumed finitely generated) instead of $\pi$ and think of $G$ as a groupoid with one object.  Then $Hom(\Pi,G)$ is the collection of groupoid homomorphisms.  Replace the conjugation action with the action of $G^{\Pi_0}$ given by $\alpha\cdot \rho(a):=\alpha(h(a))\rho(a)\alpha(t(a))^{-1}$, where $h$ is the head map and $t$ is the tail map with respect to the arrows in the groupoid.  Then the quotient of $Hom(\Pi, G)$ by $G^{\Pi_0}$ is equivalent to the original quotient $Hom(\pi,G)/G$, see [Theorem 3.4 here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.2960.pdf).  In particular, the tangent spaces are equivalent too.

To see this in play for surface groups, with some discussion about the de Rham picture in the final section, I highly recommend:

Guruprasad, K.; Huebschmann, J.; Jeffrey, L.; Weinstein, A.
*Group systems, groupoids, and moduli spaces of parabolic bundles.* 
Duke Math. J. 89 (1997), no. 2, 377–412.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this answers your question or not, but it's true that, for a connected manifold $X\,,$ $H^1(X)\cong H^1(\Pi_1(X),\mathcal{O})\,,$ where on the right hand side we are taking groupoid cohomology with coefficients in $\mathcal{O}\,.$ This is related to the Riemann-Hilbert correspondence, and it's basically saying that $H^1(X)$ classifies affine bundles on $X$ with a flat connection, up to isomorphism.

This "generalizes" the fact that $H^1(X)\cong \text{Hom}(\pi_1(X),\mathbb{R})$ since $\text{Hom}(\pi_1(X),\mathbb{R})\cong H^1(\pi_1(X),\mathbb{R})\,.$